# Assuming existence to show existence - is this a circular argument?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, solution-verification

The proof to follow is taken from a research paper in risk analysis which is in reviewing. I have been tasked with repeating the results in the paper, under a different risk measure, but I am not sure if the main argument in the paper is correct as it is presented, although I believe the main result should hold.

The context is the following. We are optimizing a risk function over a set of parameters $(a_i)_{i=1}^{m}, (b_i)_{i=1}^{m}$, with particular choices of $(a_i)_{i=1}^{m}, (b_i)_{i=1}^{m}$ denoted as $a^*, b^*$ respectively. The aim is to establish a criterion for optimality of the parameters.

The argument in the paper is as follows:

Begin by assuming that $a^*$ is chosen such that $(1)$ holds, where $(1)$ is a condition on $a^*$. It is then possible to show that there exists some $b^*$ such that a condition $(2)$ on $b^*$ holds. We then show that any $b^*$ satisfying $(2)$ is optimal given that $a^*$ is chosen according to $(1)$.
Assume next that $b^*$ is chosen such that $(2)$ holds. Then, one shows that $a^*$ can only be optimal parameters if $(1)$ holds.
The conclusion is that choosing $b^*$ such that $(2)$ holds is sufficient for obtaining optimal $(a^*, b^*)$.

There are two things that make me uneasy about this argument. Firstly, as we begin by assuming a condition on $a^*$, my instinct is to look next at what happens if $a^*$ does not satisfy $(1)$.

Secondly, it is easy to find $b^*$ such that $(2)$ does not hold. While existence of $b^*$ satisfying $(2)$ given $a^*$ such that $(1)$ holds, it seems to me like we assume existance in the second part of the proof. Then, we seemingly use the assumed existence of $b^*$ such that $(2)$ to show that we must choose $a^*$ such that $(1)$, and hence $b^*$ will exists such that $(2)$. Is this not a circular argument?

Comment: I don't think fake-proofs is an appropriate tag here. This seems to be more likely a proof that you just don't fully understand yet. Also could you possibly link the paper? Would help to be able to read the exact language used there.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @SeraPhim. I removed the tag in question. The paper has not been published yet as far as I am aware, and I am therefore hesitant to post the original text for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Saying "any $b^*$ satisfying $(2)$ is optimal *given* that $a^*$ is chosen according to $(1)$" is a bit ambiguous, as it suggests that there is a closer relationship between $a^*$ and $b^*$ than simply "if an $a^*$ with $(1)$ exists, then a $b^*$ with $(2)$ also exists, but $a^*$ and $b^*$ are linked in no other way"; that is, it suggests that given $a^*$ with $(1)$, there might exist $b^*$ with $(2)$ which is not optimal, but then that $b^*$ is completely "separated" from $a^*$. I can assume that what is most likely meant is that **the existence** of an $a^*$ satisfying $(1)$ is enough to prove that all $b^*$ satisfying $(2)$ are optimal, but obviously this depends on the actual scenario.

This ambiguity is mirrored in saying "Assume next that $b^*$ is chosen such that $(2)$ holds. Then, one shows that $a^∗$ can only be optimal parameters if $(1)$ holds". Firstly, do you mean that if $(1)$ holds, $a^*$ is optimal, or merely that $a^*$ cannot be optimal if $(1)$ doesn't hold? Secondly, and more importantly, does the entire statement mean that the authors prove that it is enough for a $b^*$ satisfying $(2)$ **to exist** in order for either **all** $a^*$ satisfying $(1)$ (even those **completely independent from $b^*$**) to also be optimal or in order to have as a fact that $a^*$ cannot be optimal if they don't satisfy $(1)$, depending on the answer to the previous question?

In the best case when both issues amount to it there being enough for the corresponding parameters to exist, there remains only to be shown that there exists $a^*$ such that $(1)$ holds, as you noted.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion to the first part; That the existence of $a^*$ s.t. $(1)$ is sufficient to show all $b^*$ s.t. $(2)$ is optimal. To be precise, the wording is as follows. We start out assuming that $a_1, \dots, a_m$ are chosen such that $(1)$ holds. Then we prove $\exists b_1, \dots, b_m $ such that $(2)$ holds. Assume then $b_1, \dots, b_m$ is chosen such that $(2)$ holds. One shows any change in either $b_i$ gives a worse objective value. We conclude that $b_1, \dots, b_m$ should be chosen such that $(2)$ holds.

Comment: For the second part: One assumes $b^*$ s.t. $(2)$ is fixed. One then continues to optimize over the remaining free parameters, namely $a_1, \dots, a_m$, and finds that any optimal solution after optimizing over $a_1, \dots, a_m$ must satisfy $(1)$, i.e, $a^*$ cannot be optimal if not $(1)$ holds given $b^*$ such that $(2)$ holds. 

It is however not enough that $\exists b^*$ s.t. $(2)$ for all $a^*$ s.t. $(1)$ to be optimal, but rather $a^*$ cannot be optimal if it does not satisfy $(1)$ whenever $b^*$ satisfying $(2)$.

Comment: The they also need to prove that there exists an $a^*$ satisfying $(1)$ which is optimal, so no, the proof that choosing $b^*$ with $(2)$ is enough is not complete.

Comment: Thank you for your insight @rosecabbagedragon. I had a similar suspicion. Do you have an example of how the argument could break down if one does not also prove $\exists a^*$ s.t. $(1)$ holds which is optimal?